# Having trouble finding correct Big O for while & if statement

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
    int i=0;
    while(i < N){
        if(nums[i] != i + 1 && nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1]){
            // swap 
            int tmp = nums[i];
            nums[i] = nums[tmp - 1];
            nums[tmp - 1] = tmp;

        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I am confused to find correct Big O for this algorithm.
Even though we will go through total N times with while loop,
if nums[i] meets the condition of if-statement, we will repeat swap until we do not meet the if-statement.

Can we say Time Complexity of this is O(N)?
or worst case of this would be O(N^2)?

Comment: When you obtain asymptotic calculation result for a if-else, glance at the worst case for Big O. It means first if can be O(n^2) as you say. So, it is O(n^2). Nice question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the problem isn't well-defined. Perhaps the OP didn't include some context. After reading the code over, it's evident that it's a sorting algorithm (a weird one). And by the way it accesses array indices, I think the algorithm expects the array `nums` of size N to be filled with integers from 1...N, not necessarily in order and there can be repeats.

Regarding SomeWittyUsername's point, let's just for this sake say that the elements don't lead to an infinite loop etc.

I did a brief annotation of the code.

```
int i=0;
    while(i < N){
        if(nums[i] != i + 1 && nums[i] != nums[nums[i] - 1]){ // 1) check if it's in the right place 2) check if the potential swap will have no effect because of a repeat.

            // Swap nums[i] with nums[nums[i]-1]
            // Why swap these two values? 
            // This effectively places num[i] where it should be in the array

            int tmp = nums[i];
            nums[i] = nums[tmp - 1];
            nums[tmp - 1] = tmp;

        } else {
            // The element is in the correct spot
            i++;
        }
    }
```

It looks like best-case scenario `nums` is initially sorted and the algorithm works in O(N) time.

But since big-O notation is supposed to refer to worst case scenario... my best answer is: It's also O(N) but with higher coefficients. It's not O(N^2) because every time it meets a misplaced element, it puts it in the right place.

Comment: (Minor aside: answers are best not addressed to other answers, or even the question author - they are primarily for many future readers. I would tend to discourage conversational items aimed at specific users. You can use comments for that, once you get to 50 points.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not well-defined problem.
It can crash and it can run indefinitely.

Crash:

Input = [100, 1] --> attempt to access array at position 99 on the first iteration

Infinite run:

Input = [2,3,4,5] --> each iteration will get to the if condition. For i == 0 there is no element in the array that equals 1 (i.e., i + 1) and since all the array elements are different it doesn't matter how they're swapped, there won't be a situation when one of them equals another. Given that, the loop will run infinitely for i == 0.